# Integral of an inverse

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let $f(x)=x^3−2x^2+5$. Then find the integral
$$\int_{37}^{149} \! f^{-1}(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$$ I know the inverse theorem for differentiation.( I don't think we can apply it here). Is there other theorem for integration.(I am not finding the inverse and then integrating).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here $f(x)$ is a cubic polynomial. $f'(x)=x(3x-4)>0$ for $x>37$. So for $x>37, f$ is increasing and hence it is a one to one and onto function from $37$ to $149$. So $f^{-1}$ exists on $[37,149]$. Now use change of variables.

Let $x=f(t)$ for $x\in [37,149]$. Then $f^{-1}(x)=t$. Then, $dx=f'(t)dt$. So, $f^{-1}(x) dx=tf'(t)dt$.

Hence, $\displaystyle \int_{37}^{149} f^{-1}(x) dx=\int_{f^{-1}(37)}^{f^{-1}(149)} tf'(t)dt$.

Comment: This cubic polynomial is not one to one.  For example, $f(0) = f(2)$.  However, it is one-to-one on the interval in question here.

Comment: Oh I see! I will edit. Thanks.

Comment: Could you can please elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

Change of variables $x = f(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

For monotonically increasing function,
$$\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}f^{-1}(x)dx=bf(b)-af(a)-\int_a^bf(x)dx$$
Here,a=4,b=6,

By the way,this result can be proved by observing the graph of a monotonic function.The function you gave is monotonically increasing in given domain.